# HTML Canvas: Delay Animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[Here](http://codepen.io/matthewkosloski/pen/ENGMrP) is an animation of a circle sliding back and forth horizontally.  It takes 10 seconds for the circle to go from `-100` to `300` back to `-100`.

This is my `drawCircle()` function, which is called via `requestAnimationFrame` (there is more code on Codepen):

```
function drawCircle() {
  // clean off canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

  // color in the background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

  // draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  if (moveRight) {
    easingValue = easeInOutExpo(iteration, -100, 400, totalIterations);
  } else {
    easingValue = easeInOutExpo(iteration, 400, -450, totalIterations);
  }
  var radius = 50;
  ctx.arc(easingValue, 125, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.closePath();

  // color in the circle
  ctx.fillStyle = "#006699";
  ctx.fill();

  if (iteration < totalIterations) {
      iteration++;
  } else {
      iteration = 0;
      moveRight = !moveRight;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to defer the execution of another "animation."  Since `requestAnimationFrame` provides a fps of 60, this 5 second animation (10 seconds including going in the alternate direction) will have a total of 300 individual frames, or `totalIterations`.  Essentially, my goal is to say, "If the current frame (`iteration`) is equal to the `totalIterations`, instead of immediately starting over, wait for 3 or 5 seconds."

A gist of what I thought might work (merely an idea):

```
var intermission = 3; // seconds to defer subsequent animation
if(elapsedSeconds % intermission === 0) { // every 3 seconds
    ctx.arc(easingValue, 125, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); // change `x` value with ease
} else {
    ctx.arc(-100, 125, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false); // stand still off canvas
}
```

I don't have a clue.  I've only used Canvas once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [javascript's `setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function at the frame you want to stop?

```
...
  if (iteration < totalIterations) {
      iteration++;
  } else {
      iteration = 0;
      moveRight = !moveRight;
  }

  if (iteration == 0 && moveRight){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle); 
    }, 3000);
  }else{
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);
  }
...
```

[codpen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbxPPZ)

another option in case you're scared of the inaccuracy of the `setTimeout` function:

```
  if (iteration < totalIterations) {
      iteration++;
  } else {
      iteration = 0;
      moveRight = !moveRight;
  }

  if (iteration == 0 && moveRight){
    var next_iter = new Date().getTime() + 3000;
    delay_restart(next_iter);
  }else{
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);
  }

}
drawCircle();

function delay_restart(start) {
  while (new Date().getTime() < start ){

  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
}
```

[codepen for second example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoeOKW)